# Need a generic repository pattern that takes two table refs and an expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I have a repository pattern which I use to access my database via `EF`. Here is one of my functions:

```
public IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
      where T : class
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Where<T>(predicate).AsQueryable<T>();
}
```

What I want to do is use something similar to achieve the following functionality:

```
from c in Context.Customers
where !Context.Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == c.ProductID)
select c;
```

I need this to work not just for "Customers" and "Products" so I need a generic approach as shown in my original repository function.

---EDIT---

I guess I'm after something like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> Filter2<T, U>(Expression<Func<T,U, bool>> predicate)
    where T : class
    where U : class
{
    return ( Context.Set<T>().Where(
             !Context.Set<U>().Any(predicate)));
}
```

I would be looking to call the function like this:

```
var result = _repository.Filter2<Products, Customers>((p, c) => p.ProductID == c.ProductID);
```

--EDIT 2--

Some more background info:

I need to check for fields in one table that aren’t referenced in another table. I need to do this for many different tables and access to the Entity framework needs to go through a repository service. I need the function that does this to be generic as I don’t want to fill the repository service with table specific functions. My requirement is to pass in an expression that defines how the check is done and some means of referencing the two tables that the expression must work against.

Comment: Why don't you just use the same function but negate the predicate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you put some mockup of the function you need? It doesn't need to be in correct syntax.

Comment: I'm struggling to see a use case for this in your particular example - why wouldn't you just do `p.ProductID != c.ProductID`?

Comment: This is quite a bizarre and unintuitive example. Why would a customer have a `ProductID`?

Comment: Martin Smith: A bit of a typo on my part about the ProductId. I just wanted to show an example of checking a link between two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you feel the need to have a generic function that does the inverse of the normal `Filter` method.  You should just pass in whatever predicate you need to the one `Filter` method.  There should be no reason you can't pass in a "not in" predicate the same way you'd pass in an "in" predicate to the same method.  Since it appears like `Customer` and `Product` are two completely separate entities (no navigation property relationship) you may have to get the collection of ProductIds separately to use in the predicate.

**Example:** *(Filling in gaps in your Repository API where necessary)*

```
var productRepository = new GenericRepository<Product>();
var productIds = productRepository.GetAll().Select(x => x.ProductId)

var customerRepository = new GenericRepository<Customer>();

// ProductId is IN Products
var customersInProducts = customerRepository.Filter(c => productIds.Contains(c.ProductId));

// ProductId is NOT IN Products
var customersNotInProducts = customerRepository.Filter(c => !productIds.Contains(c.ProductId));
```

The only difference from an IN and NOT IN in this case is the `!`.

Comment: If you look at my question (second edit section), I try to explain my requirement a little clearer. My requirement is to pass in an expression and run that expression against two tables. I don’t want to hardcode the table definitions so I want to use generics hence the <T, U> in my question. Unfortunately my original question probably didn’t use the best example for my expression as everyone seems to think the problem is about having a function to do the inverse of a normal filter. I’m sure that what I want to do can’t be done without going down the expression tree route.

Comment: @Retrocoder My solution doesn't hardcode table definitions and uses generic repository methods.  You could swap out `Product` and `Customer` for any two types of entities you want and it would still work, providing the entities had two compatible properties like `ProductId` in this example.  I understand that you want to somehow genericize this logic even further and encapsulate it inside your repository class, but since repositories typically have a 1-to-1 correlation with an entity, you might find that it's not easy to do without being incredibly awkward.

Comment: Although I started with a repository pattern doing CRUD, the changes I wanted to make made it more of a general data abstraction layer. After some experimentation it became clear that what I wanted to do, which was to keep the database access code all in one place, wasn’t going to work. I wanted a single call to the repository to return my results but I have now changed my approach. I now do what I need to do with two calls to the repository and a single line of Linq in my calling class. The Linq is working on IQueryables so I’ve kept the data access away from my veiwmodel class.

Comment: I’ve accepted your answer as it almost does what is required and my question wasn’t very well worded (I did send it just before I went home).